# My bountied question is likely not to have a answer that works. But there is an upvoted answer that doesn't actually answer the question

Tags: discussion, expired-bounty

[How could Visual Studio 2012 be set to use a custom tool to customise the Reading/writing of existing editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758748/how-could-visual-studio-2012-be-set-to-use-a-custom-tool-to-customise-the-readin)

I don't care if the bounty disappears as what I want is a working answer. Since it's unlikely that the question will/can be answered, how can I indicate that the only answer that is on the question is wrong. I've put a comment on it, but that sort of disappears in "add / show more comments" collapsed area. The primary problem is that's it's been upvoted despite being wrong.

What I'm concerned about is that the answer will have automatically have a marker on it as having gained the bounty (by default) and that may mislead future readers into thinking that it's a correct answer.

The irony is that the answer is a good one, but not to my question.

---

Update: the question got a couple of answers that though don't work in my use case, could work for others  (i.e. they are not 100% answers) so the question of awarding is now resolved.

---

Comment: Post that on your question/comment below the question, as that hasn't got so many comments.

Comment: Did it answer the question before [you changed the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19758748/revisions)?

Comment: @Arjan You could argue either way on that. That's why I refined the question.

Comment: (Just to be sure: you know you do not have to accept an answer to give it the bounty? You can even still remove the "accept" any time you like, as your Stack Overflow question is not answered yet.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you believe an answer is wrong you can down vote it and if you wish leave a comment explaining why it is wrong.  If other people agree with you they may also down vote but don't just ask people to down vote so the bounty won't be awarded.

Explaining why existing answers are incorrect can also help you getting another (hopefully more acceptable) answer which you can award the bounty to.

Flagging an incorrect answer is not a viable option because moderator action is always done under the basis that the moderator does not have subject specific knowledge.  It would be implausible for it to be otherwise given the wide ranging topics that are covered. Votes are to indicate correctness of the answers, flags are not.

Comment: Indeed - one of the reasons for declining a flag is that "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Answer (score 0):

Wrong does not always mean bad. What I mean is, that maybe for the specific case of the question it is wrong and "not working", but it still might be good in general, for other cases.

In those cases, the upvotes are a mark "this answer is good content", so letting it get half the bounty isn't so bad.